# Get a Number from a String with substring() is no working

Tags: android

I want to get an Number from a String.

My Code for this Class is:

The XML is download correct, it founds my Value String but i get not the number from the String.

```
    public class XMLProcessor extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String rssURL;
    private PostParserDelegate delegate;
    private ArrayList<Post> posts;
    String euro;
    private StringBuilder buffer;

    TextView mxntoeur;
    TextView eurtomxn;

    public XMLProcessor(String rssURL, PostParserDelegate delegate) {
        this.rssURL = rssURL;
        this.delegate = delegate;
        posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        buffer = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(rssURL);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // HTTP Status "OK" -> HTTPCODE 200
            int httpResponse = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if ( httpResponse != 200) {
                throw new Exception("Fehlercode: " + httpResponse);
            }

            InputStream input = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);

            int charactersRead;
            char[] tmpChars = new char[400];

            while (true) {
                charactersRead = reader.read(tmpChars);
                if (charactersRead <= 0) {
                    break;
                }

                buffer.append(String.copyValueOf(tmpChars, 0, charactersRead));
            }

            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("XMLProcessor", e.getMessage());
            Log.e("XMLProcessor", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        return String.valueOf(0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aDouble) {
        super.onPostExecute(aDouble);

        parse();
    }

    protected void parse()
    {
        String rawXML = buffer.toString();
        Post aPost = null;
        boolean isProcessingItem = false;
        String innerValue ="";

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new StringReader(rawXML));

            int event = parser.getEventType();
            while (event !=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                String tag = parser.getName();

                switch ( event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tag == "item" ) {
                            Log.d("XMLProcessor", "Neuer Post!");
                            isProcessingItem = true;
                            aPost = new Post();
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                            innerValue = parser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (isProcessingItem){
                            if (tag == "item") {
                                posts.add(aPost);
                                isProcessingItem = false;
                            }
                        } else if ( tag == "description") {
                            aPost.setPesoInEuro(innerValue);
                            euro = new String(innerValue.substring(13,21));
                            //euro = innerValue.substring(13,21);
                            eurtomxn.setText(euro);
                        }
                        break;
                }

                event = parser.next();
            }

            delegate.xmlFeedParsed(posts);

        }   catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("XMLProcess", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

In `innerValue` i get the Correct Sting what i need

```
/n 1.00 EUR = 21.90612 MXN<br/>\n 1.00 MXN = 0.04565 EUR<br/>\n 
<a      href="http://eur.de.fxexchangerate.com/mxn/">Converter</a>--\n 
<a href="http://eur.de.fxexchangerate.com/mxn-exchange-rates-history.html">Historische
</a>
\n.
```

But my problem is, that i need this Number `21.90612`. I have try it with `substring(13,21)`, but it was no working.

Have you a idea, how i can fix my problem?

Thank you

Comment: "but it was no working" meaning? How about using some regexp?

Comment: also note that you compare strings with equals in java, and `new String(someString)` is a *code smell*

Comment: I have try it also with this code: "euro = innerValue.substring(13,21);" so it must bring me the string from the indexnumer 13 until 21, so it must write me the number in the variable "euro". This Variable i have try it that euro is a double Variable and i have try that it is a String. But alltime this Variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what exactly is the Problem, it would be useful if you show the Exception!

Have you checked if the String innerValue has a valid lenght?

```
 if(innerValue.lenght() >= 21){euro = innerValue.substring(13,21);} else {/* Do something here!*/}
```

}